# Systemtap with Python

Tags: python-3.x, systemtap

Is there a way to probe python3 user space functions with Systemtap on Ubuntu? I'm thinking about doing something like this based on the Systemtap documentation

```
probe process("/usr/lib/python3").function("main")
{
    some handlers
}
```

When I run stap with the file above, I got

```
WARNING: cannot find module /mnt/sdb/usr/bin/python3.6 debuginfo: No DWARF information found [man warning::debuginfo]
```

Am I missing anything here and is this the right way to trace Python applications?

Answer (score 2):

This should work, but does need some python debuginfo.  If you have `debuginfod` capability in your build of elfutils/systemtap, `setenv DEBUGINFOD_URLS=https://debuginfod.elfutils.org/` and try again.  If you don't, consider downloading and installing the appropriate dbgsym from `http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/` (probably).